# How to open HP rack keyboard/monitor tray

Tags: hp, keyboard, monitoring, rack

We have maybe 5 of these HP racks.  On all of them the keyboard/monitor tray is very finicky.  Sometimes it gets stuck and the drawer tray will not open.  While stuck, repeated wiggling of the tray may eventually unstick it, but sometimes it will not.  A couple are permanently stuck at the moment.

Comment: Once you do get it open, try a bit of WD-40 (or similar) to lubricate it (but be careful not to get any on your servers). Sounds like something might be causing friction, stopping the tray from opening.

Comment: This is not likely a "friction" issue.  It's some sort of poorly designed locking mechanism, that locks it in place.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this all the time, the only solution was to go round the back and wedge a screwdriver between the clips on the rails to release it. Not the most elegant solution but worked every time.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a plausible response.  However I can't really find any place to wedge a screwdriver from the back.  I'm not sure what is meant by "clips"?  And are we talking Philips or flat head?

Answer (score 0):

We've stopped using KVMs but we used to have a lot of those and the worst one as found to have a rail misalignment, one corner was a single hole (1/3U) too high or low. Might be worth you checking that.

Comment: The rail alignment on all of them seems fine.  They slide in and out easily, as long as you don't slide it all the way in such that the lock clicks into action.